# Why does Equal["string", False] not evaluate to False?

Tags: equation-solving

Why does `Equal["string", False]` not evaluate to `False`? I would have thought *Mathematica* could prove that these two things are not equal.

Comment: I would think that *Mathematica* is unable to compare a string with a boolean; it's non-sensical. Does this usually work when comparing distinct types of variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because `Equal` treats symbols as having an indeterminate value, but as @M_goldberg points out this isn't the whole story.

```
Equal["foo", foo]
(* "foo" == foo *)
```

This is true when one side is numeric (but not a number per se) and the other is a string:

```
Equal["foo", GoldenRatio]
(* "foo" == GoldenRatio *)

Equal["foo", Sqrt[2]]  (* Sqrt can be overridden *)
(* "foo" == Sqrt[2] *)

Equal[Sqrt, Sqrt[2]]
(* Sqrt == Sqrt[2] *)
```

`Equal` also chokes on unevaluated, nonnumeric function expressions, including nonsense such as this:

```
Equal[2, 2[2]]
(* 2 == 2[2] *)
```

`Equal` will evaluate if *both* sides are numeric; also if both sides are determinate, such as comparing a string and a number.  It also evaluates to `True` if the symbols are the same, or if one is `True` and the other is `False`.  (There may be other exceptions to this rule.  Thanks to @m_goldberg for point out these examples.)

```
Equal["foo", N@Sqrt[2]]
(* False *)

Equal[True, False]
(* False *)

Equal[x, x]
(* True *)
```

Override `Sqrt`:

```
Block[{Sqrt = "foo" &},
 Equal["foo", Sqrt[2]]
 ]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Interesting. What would be the definition for "determinate"?

Comment: I suppose `String` or one of the number types.  I don't think they have a name.  It's not, for example, "atomic."

Comment: It can't be as simple as "`Equal` treats symbols as having an indeterminate value". Consider, `Equal[False, #] & /@ {True, False}` which returns `{False, True}`. Further, `Equal` clearly calls on `SameQ` and returns `True` if `SameQ` does; i.e., `Equal[x, x]` is always `True` for any `x`, including symbols.

Comment: `Equal` also considers `True` and `False` to be comparable with each other. As far as I can tell, it always remains unevaluated when the comparands are not in the same category, but what it considers a category is unclear. However it does seem that strings are in the same category as (unassigned) symbols as far as `Equal` is concerned, even if other functions treat them as distinct. `x == x` and `"x" == "x"` both give `True`. It's perhaps not as simple as falling through to `SameQ`, as the example in my comment under the other answer shows.

Comment: `"foo" == 1` giving `False` while `False == 1` remains unevaluated is a puzzling case, however.

Comment: @m_goldberg  Thanks, I didn't consider those cases.  I think `False` and `True` might be special-cased, but not fully.  The OP's example ought to evaluate to `False`, especially since `False` is `Locked`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It seems constants, numeric as well as boolean, are always treated as such -- it is puzzling.  The `Assuming` example is curious.

Comment: I agree that the OP's example ought to evaluate to `True`. Like the OP, I don't understand what `Equal` really does. The documentation is murky, saying "*lhs==rhs* returns `False` if *lhs* and *rhs* are determined to be unequal by comparisons between numbers or other raw data, such as strings." It doesn't go on to define what "other raw data" means.

Comment: +1 for elaborating what I started to say in the answer which I deleted.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks!  I don't know how much `Trace` with `TraceInternal -> True` reveals.  It suggests that `"foo" == False` matches no rewrite rule, but `True == False` does. Similarly with other cases.

Comment: Perhaps: If the args are both numeric or both evaluate to booleans, then it evaluates. Otherwise, it only evaluates if the argument's equality can't change due to future definitions.

Comment: (not counting UpValues that would make Equal[x, x] be False :P)

Comment: (2[2] can be made to evaluate to whatever by unprotecting Integer)

Comment: I think there is a rule `pat_ == pat_ = True`.  Consider `Hold@RandomReal[] == Hold@RandomReal[]` --> `True` and
RandomReal[] == RandomReal[]` --> `False` (probably).

Answer (score 6):

You have to use "===" like

```
 "string" === False
```

Or

```
SameQ["string",False]
```

Comment: I think OP probably knows this. The question is, why doesn't `Equal` give the same result? `SameQ` doesn't express a mathematical relation.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Quite frankly: I don't know, all the more so since "string"==1 returns False.

Comment: Indeed, it's a puzzling inconsistency and IMO a good question. The answer seems to be something to do with strings being treated as symbols in some contexts but not others. For example, `Solve` can't solve with respect to strings, but `Assuming["string" == False, Refine["string" == False]]` works the same with a string as it would with any other symbol.

Comment: @OleksandrR. FWIW: `Assuming["string" == False, Refine["string" == False]]` calls `PolynomialReduce[-"string" + False, {-"string" + False}, {False}, MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic]`,